# Materializecss not working on imported jsp page

Tags: html, css, jsp, materialize

I have a main jsp page with a navigation and menu bar with dropdowns, all works correctly. Based on options selected by the user a particular jsp page is imported using:

```
<c:import url="pageName.jsp"/>
```

This imported jsp also has dropdown menus on a nav bar, but don't work. From what I can tell the "data-activates" is not being picked up.

Sample list item code:

Menu bar item:

```
<li id="idMenuDynamicGroup_sort">
    <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-constrainwidth="false" data-activates="sort-dropdown">
        <i class="material-icons color-menu-font">sort_by_alpha</i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Linked menu:

```
<c:forEach var="map" varStatus="s_map" items="${on_List.orderMap}">
<c:set var="imgName" value="${map.value > 0 ? 'arrow_upward':'arrow_downward'}" />
<li>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="sortByLink(this,'list&action=setOrder&orderRef=${map.value}',${on_List.isSubsetList});">
      <i class="material-icons right" style="font-size:12px;">${imgName}</i>
        &nbsp;${map.key}
  </a>
</li>
```

All materialize and jquery CDNs are imported at the top of the main page, and the

```
<script>$(document).ready(onLoadForm());</script>
```

is run at the bottom of the main page.

This menu works perfectly on the main page, but does not display on the imported page

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

Was a stupid error in dynamically initializing the elements after loading in javascript.